# How to update shipping cost for one specific item in Magento

Tags: magento-1, shipping, payment-methods, free-shipping, fedex

I have a flat handling fee of $7.95 and free shipping for all items. But for some reasons, some items (specifically two) are showing shipping rates with FedEx of $57+ and not showing the flat rate of $7.95 which I only charge for the customer per order. How do I fix that? And why are these particular items show different numbers? Maybe because of their high price since those are the most expensive items on my website, so how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Free Shipping it will still go and get a quote. Its then overriden if free shipping applies and the $7.95 is added on as a handling fee.

You won't get rates if:

1. Authentication fails
2. Cart(package) weight not set (i.e. zero) or or over the max weight supported by FedEx
3. No connection to FedEx
4. Incorrect configuration of FedEx
5. Destination not supported by FedEx

In your case it sounds like its probably hitting issue 2 here.

If you switch on logging (under Advanced/Developer) and then set debug to true in the FedEx configuration it will show you the response from FedEx. This will tell you why no rates are found.

Resolve that and it will work.

If you are offering just free shipping then as Dan says you could do using the Fixed Rate carrier, the downside is that you can't capture scenarios such as not being able to ship to the destination, and you can't create FedEx shipping labels in Magento, so there are reasons to use the FedEx carrier even with free shipping on.

Answer (score 0):

What shipping method are you using? If you are only charging a $7.95 handling fee and free shipping why even have FedEx method turned on. Rather just use the flat rate shipping method.

If you do have FedEx enabled you may be pulling a different rate for the two items because they do not meet the weight requirement for the shipping method you have selected as free.

Comment: I am using FedEx since I have an account and it's much cheaper for shipping goods to the east coast. I checked now the weight requirement and it's set to 150 pounds which is far more than the actual weight of the items. I just noticed that in some items it also says "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time." under payment methods. Why is that happening?